# CS Circles 13 - Coding Exercise: Monkey In The Middle

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am currently working through a website called 'Computer Science Circles' and I have reached to question 13 which is all about lists.

The coding exercise is:

Write a function middle(L) which takes a list L as its argument, and returns the item in the middle position of L. (In order that the middle is well-defined, you should assume that L has odd length.) 
For example, calling middle([8, 0, 100, 12, 1]) should return 100, since it is positioned exactly in the middle of the list.

So far my code looks like this:

```
def middle(L):
    L = sorted(L)
    n = len(L)
    m = n - 1
    return (L[n/2] + L[m/2] / 2.0)
```

However, every time I run the code, it gives me a

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

I am not entirely sure how to change my code so that it can run successfully according to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `/` is performing "true" division (with `float`) while `//` is integer division.

As far as the algorithm itself, you could simply cut the length in half

```
def middle(L):
    return L[len(L)//2]

>>> middle([8, 0, 100, 12, 1])
100
```